how can I create a arrow flight server that receives more than one dataset with different schemas?
I want to send a geopandas.GeoDataFrame (a map) and a pandas.DataFrame (a coordinates list) over the network using arrow flight in python. So I would transform them to arrow data objects and send them to an arrow flight server using FlightClient.do_put. Then I want the server to receive both datasets and perform some calculation in memory. But in the server,FlightServerBase.do_get only allows one schema.
How can I receive both datasets?
I read the documentation and it does not seem to be an option to use more than one schema at the same time.

If your GeoDataFrame and DataFrame have compatible schemas (i.e., they share common fields), you can create a unified schema that encompasses both datasets.
Use the pa.unify_schemas() function from the Arrow Python library to combine multiple schemas into a single one

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@MahendranR Thank you, I solved it using something similar, I used concat_arrays, although you cannot concatenate an arrow table with a geoarrow table, I had to convert the geoarrow table to an arrow table.
